# Win 8 App - Not displaying updated data from web service

Tags: windows-8

I am creating win 8 app that access a web service and displays data on an html page.

PAGE1.html accesses the data from web service. The first time PAGE1 opens, the data is properly retrieved from web service, and I open the next page, PAGE2.html from a button click event on PAGE1 that calls `window.location("PAGE2.html`. But when I navigate back to PAGE1.html, this PAGE1.html opens but not displaying updated data.

Code of PAGE1.js of PAGE1.html: Data properly getting from web service on onload function of page.

```
ready: function (element, options) 
{
    var textDisp= document.querySelector("#text");   //text is DIV id to display data

    textDisp.innerText = "PAGE2";
    document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = function (args) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page2/page2.html");
        };
    WinJS.xhr({
       type: "GET",
        url: "http://MyWebserice",
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
    }).then(function complete(request) {
                 var resdata = request.responseText;
                 textDisp.innerText = resdata;
             }, function error(er) {
                 var err = er.statusText;
             });
     }
```

Data is properly submitted to database through web service; here is the code of PAGE2.js of PAGE2.html:

```
document.querySelector("#Submit").onclick = function (args) {
       WinJS.xhr({
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://InsertData?username=" + un + "&password=" + pass + "",
               headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
            }).then(function complete(request) {
                        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/PAGE1/PAGE1.html");
                    }, function error(er) {
                        var err = er.statusText;
            });
}
```

But PAGE1 is not showing refresh data of database after successfully adding data, I called   `WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/PAGE1/PAGE1.html")` then in WinJS.xhr to go to PAGE1.html.

Comment: so when you go back to Page1, you're seeing data, but it's the old data?  And you're seeing the request being issues again via WinJS.xhr on page 1?  After posting in Page2, can you issue the same HTTP request via Fiddler or some other external tool to confirm the correct data is retrieved?

Comment: In Page2 I am entering data and transfering to web service,not retrieving.And when I am going to Page1 from Page2 then I seeing old data in Page1.And issue is that request on Page1 via WinJS.xhr when I am going Page1 from another page.

Comment: I debugged my App with vs2012. And simultaneously I checked on Fiddler web debugger.From this I am getting issue as:
When I execute my App ,the xhr code of Page1.html executing and web service also calling and getting proper data from web service .But when I am going to another page i.e. Page2.html and coming back to my Page1.html ,then the xhr code executing but my web service not calling and And my xhr Complete method is executing and getting old data.
Thank you